# How to connect with google cloud vision API in c# with JSON file

Tags: c#

1. Enabled the Cloud Vision API
2. Downloaded the JSON file from the google cloud.

How to connect the JSON file with the c# windows application and connect with the Google cloud vision for text read from the image?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use something similar with the documentation :

[Quickstart: Using client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp)

```
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using System;

namespace GoogleCloudSamples
{
    public class QuickStart
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // jsonPath is the path to the key.json file 
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath); 
            // Instantiates a client
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(credential);
            // Load the image file into memory
            var image = Image.FromFile("wakeupcat.jpg");
            // Performs label detection on the image file
            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```